# Why is pipenv getting a UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: unicode, environment-variables, pipenv

**Problem**

I'm trying to start a virtual environment with an environment variable using `pipenv`. These are the steps that I followed:

- I created a `pipenv` virtual environment
- Ran `echo ENV_VAR=my_token > .env`
- I started the virtual environment by running `pipenv shell`

When I ran that last command, I received the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I'm using PowerShell on Windows 10.

**Question**

Why might this happen? Clearly is some odd character getting in there, but I'm using a normal keyboard.

**Context**

If I simply create my `.env` file instead, everything works as expected. Is there something weird that happens with `echo`?

**Additional**

As requested by Giacomo Catenazzi below, I've looked at the file using Notepad++. It is in UTF-16 BOM. So the echo command simply does not work very well with PowerShell to write to UTF-8.

[image: error]

Comment: Could you check in an editor, the file .env. I think you get UTF-16 (and so you hit the BOM). Powershell is know not to be UTF-8 friendly

Comment: Took a look and it seems fine? What do you think @GiacomoCatenazzi?

Comment: No, open the file and check which encoding it is showing up. From your picture (the "red disk") it seems you converted the file. My comment it was that the file is not UTF-8 (but UTF-16), but pip (and Python in general) use UTF-8 (windows is still mixed on which encoding it will use [on user side])

Comment: UTF-8 *can* have a BOM, and sometimes that causes issues. But the bytes to represent the BOM in UTF-8 are `EF BB BF` (i.e. there's no FF anywhwere to be seen). So the specific error message is weird, especially when Notepad++ can read the file correctly. Try producing a hexdump of the file and looking at the first couple of bytes.

Comment: It looks like it's using the encoding UTF-16. Is there a way to force PowerShell to write out in UTF-8 using echo?